# How to sum 2 columns and add it with the previous summed columns in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with these rows:

```
+------+--------+---------+---------+           
|  ID  |  Date  | Amount1 | Amount2 | 
+------+--------+---------+---------+
|  1   | 13 Nov |    8    |    3    |
|  2   | 11 Nov |    5    |    1    |
|  3   | 15 Nov |    0    |    3    |
|  4   | 18 Nov |    5    |    7    |
|  5   | 20 Nov |   10    |    0    |
+------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Would like to query with these result with the formula
`Total = (Amount1 - Amount2) + Previous Row's Total`

```
+------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  ID  |  Date  |  Plus   |  Minus  |  Total  |
+------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  2   | 11 Nov |    5    |    1    |    4    |
|  1   | 13 Nov |    8    |    3    |    9    |
|  3   | 15 Nov |    0    |    3    |    6    |
|  4   | 18 Nov |    5    |    7    |    4    |
|  5   | 20 Nov |   10    |    0    |   14    |
+------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is there any way to query this without binding the `Total` to a column on temporary table?

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a running total, you can use `SUM(columnname) OVER (ORDER BY sortedcolumnname)`.

To me it's actually a little counterintuitive compared to most windowed functions, as it doesn't have a partition but produces different results over the set of rows. However, it does work.

[Here is some somewhat-obfuscated documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-the-over-clause) about it.

I think you can therefore use

```sql
SELECT  mt.[ID], 
        mt.[Date], 
        mt.[Amount1] AS [Plus], 
        mt.[Amount2] AS [Minus], 
        SUM(mt.[Amount1] - mt.[Amount2]) OVER (ORDER BY mt.[Date], mt.[ID]) AS Total
FROM    mytable mt
ORDER BY mt.[Date], 
         mt.[ID];
```

And here are the results - they match yours.

```
ID  Date        Plus  Minus  Total
2   2020-11-11  5     1      4
1   2020-11-13  8     3      9
3   2020-11-15  0     3      6
4   2020-11-18  5     7      4
5   2020-11-20  10    0      14
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the demo Tim - I was just about to put one in.

Comment: I couldn't wrap my head around this question for some reason.  I tested your answer, saw that it worked, and decided to add the demo link.

Comment: @Tim - I agree - I find it counterintuitive and felt the same the first time I saw one of these: I thought the last column must be the same on every row.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using CTE first followed by self join. For amount1 - amount2, for id=3, you will be getting 0 -3 = -3. So, for id 3, the result below will be different for id=3

```sql
DECLARE @t table(id int, dateval date, amount1 int, amount2 int)

INSERT INTO @t 
values
  (1 ,'2020-11-13', 8, 3),    
  (2 ,'2020-11-11', 5, 1),    
  (3 ,'2020-11-15', 0, 3),    
  (4 ,'2020-11-18', 5, 7),    
  (5 ,'2020-11-20',10, 0);
  
  ;WITH CTE_First AS
  (
  SELECT id, dateval, amount1 as plus, amount2 as minus, (amount1-amount2) as total ,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateval) as rnk
  FROM @t 
  )
  SELECT c.ID, c.DATEVAL, c.plus,c.minus,c.total + isnull(c1.total,0) as new_total
  FROM CTE_First AS c
  left outer join CTE_First AS C1
  on C1.rnk = c.rnk- 1
```

```
+----+------------+------+-------+-----------+
| ID |  DATEVAL   | plus | minus | new_total |
+----+------------+------+-------+-----------+
|  2 | 2020-11-11 |    5 |     1 |         4 |
|  1 | 2020-11-13 |    8 |     3 |         9 |
|  3 | 2020-11-15 |    0 |     3 |         2 |
|  4 | 2020-11-18 |    5 |     7 |        -5 |
|  5 | 2020-11-20 |   10 |     0 |         8 |
+----+------------+------+-------+-----------+
```